# how to convert text values in an array to float and add in python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

i have a text file containing the values:

```
120 25 50
149 33 50
095 41 50
093 05 50
081 11 50
```

i extracted the  values  in the first column and put then into an array: **adjusted**

how do i convert the values from  text to float and add 5 to each of them using a **for**  loop?

my desired output is :

```
125
154
100
098
086
```

here is my code:

```
adjusted = [(adj + (y)) for y in floats]

A1 = adjusted[0:1]
A2 = adjusted[1:2]
A3 = adjusted[2:3]
A4 = adjusted[3:4]
A5 = adjusted[4:5]
print A1
print A2
print A3
print A4
print A5


A11= [float(x) for x in adjusted]
FbearingBC = 5 + float(A11)
print FbearingBC
```

it gives me errors it says i cant add float and string
pliz help

Comment: you can just cast as following: `float(number_string)`. Also, what line does it give you error on?

Comment: on the line :FbearingBC = 5 + float(A11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have:

```
adjusted = ['120', '149', '095', ...]
```

The simplest way to convert to float and add five is:

```
converted = [float(s) + 5 for s in adjusted]
```

This will create a new list, iterating over each string `s` in the old list, converting it to `float` and adding `5`.

Assigning each value in the list to a separate name (`A1`, etc.) is not a good way to proceed; this will break if you have more or fewer entries than expected. It is much cleaner and less error-prone to access each value by index (e.g. `adjusted[0]`) or iterate over them (e.g. `for a in adjusted:`).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [float(value)+5 for value in adjusted]
[125.0, 154.0, 100.0, 98.0, 86.0]
```

This is a list comprehension, so it does all the functions of converting to floats, adding 5 and appending them to a list all in one line. However, if all of your numbers are integers you should convert it to an `int` so you don't have all of the `.0`s.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
with open('your_text_file.txt', 'rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(float(line.split()[0]) + 5)
```

It will display:

```
125.0
154.0
100.0
98.0
86.0
```

Or of you need all your values in a list:

```
with open('your_text_file.txt', 'rt') as f:
    values = [float(line.split()[0]) + 5 for line in f]
print (values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading the data from a file, this could done as below:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r+') as f: # where data.txt is the file containing your data
    for line in f.readlines(): # Get one line of data from the file
        number = float(line.split(' ')[0]) # Split your data by ' ' and get the first number.
        print "%03d" % (number + 5) # Add 5 to it and then print using the format "%03d"
```

Hope this helps.